# Какой статус HTTP нужно отдавать пока сайт обслуживается

Tags: http

Например, мы что-то чиним на сайте и закрываем к нему доступ: все запросы перенаправляются на информационную страничку.

Какой статус HTTP нужно отдавать; в частности, имеется в виду поисковым роботам?

Comment: 503 ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все статусы HTTP описаны в **[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)** в секции **[10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10)**. Ознакомьтесь, возможно, найдете еще что-либо интересное для себя. В данный же момент, вероятно, Вам нужно вот это:

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
> temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication
> is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after
> some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
> Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
> handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> *Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish to
> simply refuse the connection.*